# ValueError at /cart/ Cannot assign "'admin'": "CartItem.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I get ValueError when i try and save an object, The error is related to User being assigned to a model. When i use without string method (only user=request.user) it says TypeError at /cart/
**str** returned non-string (type User)
when i apply string method (user=str(request.user)) it gives me ValueError at /cart/ Cannot assign "'admin'": "CartItem.user" must be a "User" instance.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .models import Book, CartItem
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import BookForm
# Create your views here.
def signupuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html')
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                    user.save()
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'main/UserCreated.html')
                except IntegrityError:
                    return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
            else:
                return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Passwords did not match'})

def signinuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html', {'error':'You are already logged in'})
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm()})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is None:
                return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm(), 'error':'Username and password did not match'})
            else:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'main/loggedin.html', {'error':'You are now logged in!'})
 
def logoutuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET": 
            return render(request, 'main/logoutuser.html')
        elif request.method == "POST":
            logout(request)
            return render(request, 'main/loggedin.html', {'error':'You are now logged out!'})
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html', {'error':'You are not logged in'})
    

def home(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books})


@login_required
def addtocart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bookid = CartItem.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])
        form = CartItem.objects.create(book=bookid, user=str(request.user), commit=False)
        newCartItem = form.save(commit=False)
        newCartItem.user = request.user
        newCartItem.save()
        return redirect('home')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':BookForm})
```

home.html

```
<h1>Here are products</h1>
{% for book in books %}
<h3>{{ book.name }}</h3>
<img src= "/media/{{ book.image }}" alt="">
<p>{{ book.description }}</p>
<form method="POST" action="/cart/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="bookid" value="{{ book.id }}">Add to cart</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
"""EBook URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from core import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name='signupuser'),
    path('login/', views.signinuser, name='signinuser'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutuser, name='logoutuser'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('cart/', views.addtocart, name='cart'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class CartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import CartItem

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['book', 'user']
```

Comment: If you require the cart to be updated by non-loggedin / guest users, you need to remove the @login_required decorator

Comment: You are using the models create method like a form for some reason? please show your code for BookForm which you pass in the context for get method

Comment: ```from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import CartItem

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['book', 'user']```

Comment: im not currently using forms.py tho

Comment: I'm logged in via an account

Comment: I noticed you were passing it in the context. Anyway I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you were using a form and then after changing the code used the Models create method like it was a form and also using the books id to get a CartItem? Change your view like so:

```
@login_required
def addtocart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])
        except Book.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('home')
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(book=book, user=request.user)
        return redirect('home')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {})
```

I removed the form from the context because it looked like you didn't use it.